# Hashing function in custom hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I was reading an article about creating a custom hashmap. 
Couldn't understand their getSupplementalHash() function implementation. It goes like this:

```
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
```

Can anyone explain to me how this works?

Ref: https://tekmarathon.com/2013/03/11/creating-our-own-hashmap-in-java/

Comment: Is your question literally "How do the `>>>`, `^`, and `^=` operators work?"  Or is it more like "Why _that_ particular series of operations for a hash function, rather than some other?"

Comment: It's literally a function to mess around with the hash some more to make it more hashy.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson, I want to know why that particular series of operations, precisely.